# Foreign undergraduate study possibilities for a student in Southeastern Europe

Tags: discussion

I don't have particularly strong feelings about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89566/foreign-undergraduate-study-possibilities-for-a-student-in-southeastern-europe#question) either way, but it seems a little off-topic to me. I don't want to take unilateral action, so what does everyone else think? (I know there are vague precedents, such as the question about REUs in Europe (?), but I also think that those questions are off-topic.)

Comment: I am only mildly inclined to leave it open as there are similar questions asking about which school to go to, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38537/graduate-studies-in-number-theory and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/does-it-ever-make-sense-not-to-go-to-the-most-prestigious-graduate-school-you-ca .  This is not a good reason though, and perhaps all these questions are off topic. One thing to ask is "will that question, and the answers appearing there, be useful to others _besides_ the OP?"

Comment: I think that this should at least be CW... It's off topic, but somewhat on topic.

Comment: (@Asaf: heh, a set theorist who allows non-excluded middles.) I also feel lukewarm to it. But do not think the case is so clear cut.